# wp_nav_menu() doesn't assign ul class

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Using `wp_nav_menu()` doesn't seem to allow me to properly assign a class to my `ul` element. Here's my code for the menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left',
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
) );
```

The issue is that this keeps assigning my menu classes as container classes, even though I've tried setting container to false and to `''`. This ends up being my navbar html:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-31"><a href="https://wordpress-c9-bradydowling.c9.io/?page_id=31">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="https://wordpress-c9-bradydowling.c9.io/?page_id=5">My Little Page</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="https://wordpress-c9-bradydowling.c9.io/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the [gist of my full header.php](https://gist.github.com/bradydowling/782925c69c8d4a3b9e20) file in case that's relevant. According to the [wp_nav_menu docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), this seems exactly the way I should be calling it.

Is there a setting somewhere or a version of a certain plugin that could be messing things up? Does it matter that I'm updated to Wordpress 4.4.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "nav navbar-nav navbar-left" is applied to "container".
In other words, it overwrites the "container_class".

If the menu is set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "ul".

Comment: Maybe this is common WP terminology (which I'm not familiar with) but perhaps you could make it clearer that you need to check the box next to the menu name to set the menu for your theme.

Comment: As a side note, in my theme should I make this conditional and say if it's not set it should just grab some list of pages that I style? It seems like this is a really easy way of accidentally having a non-styled menu before settings are adjusted in WP admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the answer that is checked to be the solution didnt work for me. I found out I had made a small mistake. The name of my menu didnt match with this function: `register_nav_menus`

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was absent class in `items_wrap` template

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
```